# Can i add a setter and getter to a variable without adding any object variables

Tags: javascript

I tried setting the variable directly with get() but I don't know what the correct syntax would be, since it varies, also I tried putting it in an object without a name. This also did not work, if it's not possible is there anything similar

```
var foo = {
     set (bar){

     }
     get(){
         return 1
     }
}
```

Well originally I wanted to make a value that also appends to all of its values to a array, whenever it was modified . 
This was the first thing I thought of,

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd like to interact with `foo`, and the expected behavior?

Comment: what is `baz` here? you can not declare functions like this in an object itself. You have to use identifiers e.g.

`var foo = {
     set: (bar) => {

     },
     get: () => {
         return bar
     }
}`
maybe this should work.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: you need to name the property in `set` and `get`

Answer (score 2):

Use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for window object.

[image: Example use of Object.defineProperty]

Answer (score -2):

You don't need getter/setters when you access explicit defined properties of an object:

```js
// no need for getters/setters here:
var foo = {
    bar: 123
};
console.log(foo.bar); // 123
foo.bar = 456;
console.log(foo.bar); // 456
```

You have to define getter/setters, when you want to work with a "virtual" properties, it means with properties which are not explicitly defined in the object.

Here the getter/setter is necessary, because `fullname` is not an explicit property of the `person` object:

```js
var person = {
  firstname: "Albert",
  lastname: "Einstein",

  get fullname() {
    return this.firstname +" "+this.lastname;
  },
  set fullname(_name){
    var words = _name.toString().split(' ');
    this.firstname = words[0];
    this.lastname = words[1];
  }
};
person.fullname = "Issac Newton";
console.log(person.firstname); // "Issac"
console.log(person.lastname);  // "Newton"
console.log(person.fullname);  // "Issac Newton"
```

**EDIT:** You can define custom getters/setters even on explicit properties for checking type or other conditions, as pointed out by @iArcadia.

Comment: I understand but, I was just curious if this was possible although it's not the most applicable/useful thing ever, thank you for typing a response as well.

Comment: @TheronAkubuiro it is definitely possible as shown in the second snippet in my answer.

Comment: Define custom s/getters on explicit properties can be used for checking type or some other conditions.